# Bitbake: force one task of a recipe and all following

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I want to force-recompile a package, like that:

```
bitbake -f -c compile mypackage
```

However, I also want all following tasks to be executed (like `install`, `package`, etc.), just as if I had called `bitbake mypackage` from a completely clean state. Can this be done in *one* step, rather than the following two?

```
bitbake -f -c compile mypackage
bitbake mypackage
```

Or as an alternative solution, can I somehow "taint" the compile-task, such that executing `bitbake mypackage` does everything from compilation onwards?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is exactly what -C is for:

```
bitbake -C compile mypackage
```

This will run mypackage:do_build and force mypackage:do_compile to execute.  Strictly speaking, it taints mypackage:do_compile (so that it has to execute) and then executes mypackage:do_build, which is exactly what you wanted.

Comment: What does tainting mean in this respect?

Comment: 'contaminate or pollute (something).'.  Mark it as dirty, which means it has to be re-executed.

Comment: @RossBurton - Can I do the same for the `mypackage:do_install` task? Meaning, say at the first time I built the entire package by executing `bitbake mypackage`. Then I (manually) changed the implementation of the `do_install` task so that, for example, it will remove (`rm -f`) some files that `mypacakge` installs in the final image root FS. Can I do that to the `do_install"? Will it be as follows: `bitbake -C install mypackage`?

Comment: Yes, but if you changed the recipe then just `bitbake mypackage` will work fine.